# send picture with reactjs and dropzone

Tags: jquery, reactjs, dropzone.js

i have this code, that send a image with reactjs and the component dropzone, but i dont sure why don't work, i don understand what is the problem or what is the value that i should send

```
render(){
    return(
        <Dropzone
          accept="image/jpeg, image/png"
          onDrop={this.sendImg.bind(this)} 
        >
        </Dropzone> 
    )
}


sendImg(e){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/api/uploadImg/',
      data: e[0],
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
          console.log(err);
      }.bind(this)
    });

}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Remove the `.bind(this)` from `onDrop`. `sendImage` should accept `acceptedFiles` as a param which is an array of uploaded files. Looks like they have usage instructions in their docs, did you start there? https://react-dropzone.netlify.com/

Comment: thanks, but i dont know what is the diference, if i do a console.log(e) in sendImg, the message is the same

Comment: What does it log?